# Calling an specific Array of Functions

Tags: javascript, html

I want to call an specific array of function on my onclick.

Example JS:

```
var foo = [
  function() { alert("Function 1!"); },
  function() { alert("Function 2!"); }
];
```

Example HTML:

```
<a onclick="foo[0]" >Alert</a>
```

but dont understand how get it done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need parenthesis for calling the function. Otherwise you return the function itself, like in example 2.

```
<a onclick="foo[0]()" >Alert</a>
<!--              ^^         -->
```

```js
var foo = [
    function() { alert("Function 1!"); },
    function() { alert("Function 2!"); }
];
```

```html
<a onclick="foo[0]()" >Alert</a><br>
<a onclick="alert(foo[0])" >Alert, what really happens without parenthesis</a>
```

Comment: as plain as the nose on your face, stupid me and thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

you should call the function . since you are getting only function using `foo[0]` . you need to call them by `()` to run the function

```js
var foo = [
  function() { alert("Function 1!"); },
  function() { alert("Function 2!"); }
];
foo[0]();
foo[1]();
```